# GWT project deployment to tomcat in STS(Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, tomcat

I have a maven project in STS(Eclipse) and I try deploying it to Tomcat 6 in STS. For maven install I use gwt-maven-plugin. Installed war contains all folders (WEB-INF/, META-INF/, compiled GWT frontend folder). When I deploy this project to tomcat (in STS), there are only WEB-INF and META-INF folders in webapps/project folder. Folder with compiled GWT frontend is nowhere to find.  In context.xml I even tried to set docBase to installed war, but no difference in result. Have anyone an idea where problem could be?, because now I have to manually copy this folder to unpacked folder in webapps. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a configuration problem, post your gwt-maven-plugin xml here.
Here's mine, just for reference

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${gwt.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <logLevel>DEBUG</logLevel>
        <style>PRETTY</style>
        <runTarget>/ApplicationScaffold.html</runTarget>
        <hostedWebapp>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</hostedWebapp>
        <!--                    <modules><module>${project.groupId}.Main</module></modules>-->
        <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
        <debugPort>8001</debugPort>
        <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx900m</extraJvmArgs>
        <!-- instruct plugin not to require open browser in test mode -->
        <mode>htmlunit</mode>
        <!-- compiler speed up -->
        <draftCompile>true</draftCompile>
        <optimizationLevel>0</optimizationLevel>
        <disableAggressiveOptimization>true</disableAggressiveOptimization>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- must override the plugin's default dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```